# redirect after account activation for forum using bbpress and buddypress

Tags: redirect, buddypress, wp-redirect, bbpress

I have a site with a forum and am using bbpress and buddypress to control the forum. After you register you are sent an activation email and when you click the link in the email it takes you to the site with a message that reads "Your account was activated successfully! You can now log in with the username and password you provided when you signed up." where 'log in' is clickable. When you click that it takes you to the standard grey Wordpress login page and I would like it to take you to the forum page where you can login. I'm not sure if that is in a template or function somewhere or if there is a way to redirect it. I am new to both bbpress and buddypress.

Comment: so basically you want your forum page to be your login page for all the users ?? Also, you can redirect users to forum page after they login from the Standard WordPress login page.

Comment: No just the login for the forum users, if that is possible. After they click the activation link in their email they are taken to that "Your account was activated successfully!" page and I'd like that link on that page to take them to the forum page. I guess if that is not possible I can redirect to the forum after the wordpress login page as an option.